# What software for on screen keyboard - Raspberry Pi resistive touch HDMI minotor and Ubuntu Mate

Tags: raspberry-pi, virtual-keyboard

I put a [5" resistive touch HDMI display](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U21UA16) (I didn't get mine from Amazon, but I think this is the same thing) on a Raspberry Pi 3, and it came loaded with an Ubuntu Mate distro with the touch drivers.  So now the OS sees the clicks from the display.  I'd like to add an onscreen keyboard that pops up when I touch in a text box.  In this particular project, I'd like it to do that all the time, but for other projects, it'd be nice if it could figure out the difference between a touch and a click.  I don't know how feasible that is on a resistive overlay though.

Also in the future, I'd like to build this same sort of thing with other SBCs like the ODROID C1+ and maybe do Android.

There is a keyboard called "OnBoard" available in Ubuntu Mate, but I can't seem to get it to autostart, nor reliably show up after selecting a text box in Firefox.